# Mission Control Won't Open and How Do you set up control + up arrow to make it work

Tags: terminal, mac, spaces, mission-control

Hello I'm trying to use the control + up arrow to see my desktops/apps that are open but it's not working. I am on 10.13.6 High Sierra.

I have spaces enabled and for some reason, the mission control won't work. I have tried the "killall Dock" in the terminal but that doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: Please add the version of macOS on this system to your original question, as the version of macOS is vital to getting you a correct answer.

Comment: 10.13.6 High Sierra

Comment: Can't you use the Finder button to open Mission Control?  It should appear in your dock.

Comment: I double click it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Does it display the correct keyboard shortcut in Mission Control Settings? Try changing the shortcut to something else and then changing it back to your desired shortcut.

[image: Mission Control Settings]

Comment: Hmmm That didn't work.